# RegExp working in JSFiddle but not in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, babeljs

I have the regular expression:

```
/(?:!!)(.+)(?:!!)(?:\(zoomOn )([\S,]+)(?:\))/g
```

It matches something like `!!some text!!(zoomOn 1,2,3)`.

This works okay in the browser ([JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/674urj2g/)) but not in Node. I am writing in ES2015, using Babel and the [es2015 preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/).

For extra insight this is for a Showdown extension. I noticed the [twitter extension](https://github.com/showdownjs/twitter-extension/blob/master/src/showdown-twitter.js) add some extra `\` to the RegExps. Is this a quirk of Node/ES5 I'm not aware of?

## Update

I was hoping I wouldn't need to post the code for Node since I thought it would just be a node quirk.

Anyway, the code is for an extension to Showdown:

```
# extensions.js
export const manipulationAPIExtensions = () => [
  {
    // [zoomOn node1,node2,node3,...](some text)
    type: 'lang',
    filter: (text, converter, options) => {
      const toReturn = text.replace(/(?:!!)(.+)(?:!!)(?:\(zoomOn )([\S,]+)(?:\))/g, (match, innerText, nodeString) => {
        const nodes = nodeString.split(/\s*,\s*/);
        let nodeArrayAsString = '[';
        nodes.forEach(node => {
          nodeArrayAsString += `'${node}',`;
        });
        nodeArrayAsString += ']';
        return `<a onclick="pathwayInstance.manipulator.zoomOn(${nodeArrayAsString})">${text}</a>`;
      });
      return toReturn;
    },
  },
];
```

This is used in Showdown as follows:

```
export const getShowdown = (KaavioInstance) => {
  window.diagram = KaavioInstance;
  Showdown.extension('kaavio', manipulationAPIExtensions());
  return new Showdown.Converter({
    extensions: ['kaavio'],
  });
};
```

And then in my unit test:

```
describe('CustomMarkdown', () => {
  // Don't really need Kaavio since we are only checking the output HTML
  const mockKaavioInstance = {};
  const converter = getShowdown(mockKaavioInstance);
  console.log(converter.getAllExtensions())

  describe('Kaavio', () => {
    it('should return the correct HTML from the markdown', () => {
      const markdown = normalize(fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/extensions/Kaavio.md`, 'utf8'));
      const HTML = normalize(fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/extensions/Kaavio.html`, 'utf8'));

      const output = converter.makeHtml(markdown);

      assert.equal(output, HTML);
    });
  });
});
```

The unit test fails since no match is found.

If I do something simple like the below it works. Of course the unit test doesn't work but if I console.log it out then I get the expected result of `matched`.

```
# extensions.js
export const manipulationAPIExtensions = () => [
  {
    // [zoomOn node1,node2,node3,...](some text)
    type: 'lang',
    filter: (text, converter, options) => {
      const toReturn = text.replace(/./g, (match) => {
        return 'matched';
      });
      return toReturn;
    },
  },
];
```

Comment: Are you saying that if you execute the exact same code in Node, it doesn't match? That seems unlikely.

Comment: @felixkling. It does seem unlikely, but it seems to be the case. Very perplexing

Comment: whats the code you are using in node?  asking since alerts dont exist there and thats what you used in your fiddle.

Comment: May the problem is babel... I executed following code in node and got true as result:
console.log((/(?:!!)(.+)(?:!!)(?:\(zoomOn )([\S,]+)(?:\))/g).test("!!some test!!(zoomOn 1,2,3)"));

Comment: @archos that should result in true. That means the regex is working.

Comment: @JohnVandivier Yes, but as he said above it has not worked in Node in his case...

Comment: Working just fine.

Comment: Okay that's strange. I've dumped all of the code I used in node with some explanation

Comment: Generally you should trim down your code to something simple that reproduces the issue. Give us simple inputs and outputs, otherwise the issue could be anywhere, or not even be regex-related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is embarrassing but a lesson in checking all called functions learned. The `normalize()` function that is called in these lines:

```
const markdown = normalize(fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/extensions/Kaavio.md`, 'utf8'));

const HTML = normalize(fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/extensions/Kaavio.html`, 'utf8'));
```

was replacing white spaces with bullet characters... Thanks for the help regardless!

Answer (score 0):

That works for me in Node, just tried it, but that fiddle uses an alert(). You need to use something like console.log() that Node understands.

```
var text = '!!some text!!(zoomOn node1)';
text.replace(/(?:!!)(.+)(?:!!)(?:\(zoomOn )([\S,]+)(?:\))/g, function (match, innerText, nodeString) {
    console.log("matched!");
})
```

Maybe you have some other code you didn't post which is interfering?

Comment: Thanks for testing! I've dumped all of the code in Node in an update to the question.

Comment: Please provide your package.json, grunt, and .babelrc files. This code won't run based on the showdownjs base npm test. It doesn't pass the linter.